# React Component not re rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So as I understand, a component will re-render when there has been a change in `props` and `componentWillMount` shall run before re-rendering. At the moment my constructor and `componentWillMount` run as expected, but then the question `prop` changes which I need to update the user score state, but this change in question prop doesn't trigger the constructor or `componentWillMount`. As I shouldn't update the state inside the render function (the only place so far that I have been able to get access to the updated question `prop`), how can I make react recognise this change in it's `props` and then update the state? Hope that's understandable.

Here is my container

```
class FullTimeScoreContainer extends Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userHomeScore: 1,
            userAwayScore: 1
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        getFTSAnswerStatus(this.props.question).then(foundScores => {
            if ( foundScores.userHomeScore ) {
                this.setState({
                    userHomeScore: foundScores.userHomeScore,
                    userAwayScore: foundScores.userAwayScore
                });
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { option, question, questionIndex, user, configs, renderAs, showNextQuestionAfterFTS, total} = this.props;

        // check if question is active or not
        let ComponentClass;
        if ( question[0].active ) {
            ComponentClass = FullTimeScoreActive;
        } else {
            ComponentClass = FullTimeScoreLocked;
        }

        const changeScoreState = (team, val) => {
            switch (team) {
                case "home":
                    this.setState( (prevState) => ({ userHomeScore: prevState.userHomeScore + val }) );
                    break;
                case "away":
                    this.setState( (prevState) => ({ userAwayScore: prevState.userAwayScore + val }) );
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Error("unrecognised team to change score state")
            }
        }

        const onClickCallback = () => {
            const p = this.props;
            const s = this.state;
            p.showNextQuestionAfterFTS();
            p.recordFullTimeScoreAnswer(s.userHomeScore, s.userAwayScore, p.question, p.questionIndex, p.user, p.configs)
        }

        return (
            <ComponentClass
                imgSrc={imgSrc}
                user={user}
                answerStatus={answerStatus}
                question={question}
                onClickCallback={onClickCallback}
                questionIndex={questionIndex}
                total={total}
                configs={configs}
                userScores={this.state}
                changeScoreState={changeScoreState}
            />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        configs: state.configs,
        user: state.user
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ recordFullTimeScoreAnswer, showNextQuestionAfterFTS }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FullTimeScoreContainer);

export { FullTimeScoreContainer }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the question, but I think you are looking for `componentDidMount`

Comment: componentDidMount would be better to use than `componentWillMount`

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I have tried both and it hasn't worked. the constructor and mounting functions have outlived their lifecycle by the time the question prop has been updated

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillMount` will only run before the **first** render. It doesn't get run before **every** render. So even if your `state` and `props` update, `componentWillMount` will not get called again.

The `constructor` function is the same as well.

You might be looking for `componentWillReceiveProps` ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)). This lifecycle event is called when a **mounted** component is about to receive new props. You can update your `state` in this lifecycle event.

Note that `componentWillReceiveProps` only works on **mounted** components. Therefore, it will not get called the first time your component receives its' initial props.

A side note: [Per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount), you also don't want to introduce any side-effects or subscriptions in `componentWillMount`. Do that in `componentDidMount` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would like add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation...

> a component will re-render when there has been a change in props

As I understand, you can't change the props, so component re-render on state changes.

Comment: Not exactly - if props get changed upstream then the component will update. You are correct in that you can't change the props of a component from itself. It doesn't look like OP makes direct changes to props

Comment: Thanks for the information @KevinHoerr